# jQuery get parameters from class and use them on functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function, jquery-plugins

I have two bits of code: a form and a jQuery function.

My problem is that I would like to get class attributes and use them on the form validation function. I am using Validity JS for validation.

This is what I have:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="field_01" class=".require().minLength(5)" />
```

and in the JS function:

```
var checks_to_apply = $("#field_01").attr("class").split(" "), 
i, l;

var checks = "";

for (i = 0, l = checks_to_apply.length; i < l; i++) {

        checks += checks_to_apply[i];
    }
$("#field_01")+checks;
...
...
```

The right behaviour here is not respected.

This is what I get from a "checks" alert:

```
.require().minLength(5)
```

but executing in that way it is not the same as doing it directly in the jQuery function like:

```
$("#field_01").require().minLength(5);
```

Where am I wrong, I think that the problem in the method may be because it is seeing `.require().minLength(5)` as a string and not as jQuery code to execute.

Any idea on how to fix it, please?

Comment: `.require().minLength(5)` is that a valid class name? You could use `data` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are executing these functions on a particular object you would need to create the whole argument as an string and execute it via eval():

```
var checks_to_apply = $("#field_01").attr("class").split(" "), 
i, 
l;

var checks = "$('#field_01')";

for (i = 0, l = checks_to_apply.length; i < l; i++) {
   checks += checks_to_apply[i];
}
eval(checks);
```

But i would advise you to use a different validation plugin, because you are misusing the class attribute: Check out http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ for a much better and cleaner annotation.

Comment: thank you for your inputs, they were the right way to achieve what i need.

eval('$("#field_01")'+checks);

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you want something like this

Firstly change here `class="require minLength" minlengthdata="5"`

```
    var classes = $('#field_01').attr('class').split(" ");
    var data = $('#field_01').attr('minlengthdata');

   for (i = 0, i < classes ;  i++) {
      if(classes[i] == 'require'){
   alert('its a requred field');
        }
    if(classes[i] == 'minLength' && data > 0){
   alert('minimum value required');
        }


  }
```

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use this method as i have many many validation types and i use the validity plugin which already has checks for them, I just needed to call the right method from the class attribute